JSplitPane re-executes initGL()
I'm trying to make a GUI-based game engine (for learning with experience)
I have my initGL() method here
@Override
public void initGL() {
    createCapabilities();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    Main.init();
    try {
        Main.main(null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

(This is just for testing i will improve it later)
The main class was my class which used GLFW before I tried making it with Swing, I didn't want to move everything so that is how I left it. The issue arises when I try to use a JSplitPane. I'm making a GUI based game engine like I said, so customizing the size of each window would be useful. But whenever I try resizing the window, it restarts OpenGL or at least executes the initGL() method again.
How would I know that it's getting executed again?
My Main.main(null) method creates a JFrame which contains JSliders to modify certain properties of rendering. Everytime I resize the window it opens another one of those JFrames
And for all those who want a MRE, I've customized the sample provided on their GitHub page to add a JSplitPane
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.createCapabilities;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glColor3f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2f;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.awt.AWTGLCanvas;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.awt.GLData;

public class AWTTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("AWT test");
        JPanel emptyPanel = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPane;
        GLData data = new GLData();
        AWTGLCanvas canvas;
        
        emptyPanel.add(new JButton("E"));

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.add(canvas = new AWTGLCanvas(data) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void initGL() {
                System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + effective.majorVersion + "." + effective.minorVersion
                        + " (Profile: " + effective.profile + ")");
                createCapabilities();
                glClearColor(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f, 1);
            }

            @Override
            public void paintGL() {
                int w = 600;
                int h = 600;
                float aspect = (float) w / h;
                double now = System.currentTimeMillis() * 0.001;
                float width = (float) Math.abs(Math.sin(now * 0.3));
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
                glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glColor3f(0.4f, 0.6f, 0.8f);
                glVertex2f(-0.75f * width / aspect, 0.0f);
                glVertex2f(0, -0.75f);
                glVertex2f(+0.75f * width / aspect, 0);
                glVertex2f(0, +0.75f);
                glEnd();
                swapBuffers();
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, emptyPanel, canvas);

        frame.add(splitPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.transferFocus();

        Runnable renderLoop = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                canvas.render();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(renderLoop);
    }
}

Thank you
(This is reposted from GitHub as i was not getting any response)

Do you know for an absolute fact that the origin of the bug in your code resides in the code that you've shown us in this question, and that this is all the information that anyone would need to be able to answer this question? If this were my problem, I'd create a new separate program that attempted to minimize the code to the bare minimum required to compile and run and yet demonstrates the error, basically to fully isolate the bug as much as possible, a [mre].

What is the name of the class(es) that extend from AWTGLCanvas and where in your code do you call the constructors for these classes ?

@HovercraftFullOfEels Added a MRE, however there's a new issue, I can't even use the split bar.
